# Spark query sql server

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

i'm trying to query SQL server using Spark/scala and running into an issue

here is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


object temp {  
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("temp").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;databaseName=test;user=XX;password=XXXXXXX;"
val jdbcDbTable = "[test].dbo.[Persons]"
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,
"dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable)).load()
jdbcDF.show(10)
println("Complete")
  }
}
```

below is the error and i assume it is complaining about main method - but why ?how to fix it.
error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.(SQLContext.scala:70)
    at apachetika.temp$.main(sqltemp.scala:24)
    at apachetika.temp.main(sqltemp.scala)
18/09/28 16:04:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is due to a scala version mismatch

The library compiled with `spark_core` dependence with scala 2.11 instead of scala 2.10. Use scala 2.11.8+.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this had no impact. I'm able to run other code successfully in the same compiler settings